# Travis-ci - undefined references c++

Tags: c++, cmake, travis-ci

My Travis-ci build keeps failing with undefined reference, Heres is the build log

- [build](https://travis-ci.com/HeraKumi/hoshiMenu/builds/80727654)
- [Cmake file](https://files.catbox.moe/4vdt6m.txt)
- [Travis file](https://files.catbox.moe/n92xgi.yml)

How would I go about solving this 'undefined reference' from ncurses?
I have built ncurses from source as well as have the 'CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS' set to "-lncurses", but it doesn't seem to execute the 'CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS', I think.

for non links

cmake -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(hoshiMenu)
include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(CURLPP REQUIRED curlpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lncurses")

add_executable(hoshiMenu main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hoshiMenu ${CURLPP_LDFLAGS})
```

travis build error part -

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target hoshiMenu
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hoshiMenu.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable hoshiMenu
CMakeFiles/hoshiMenu.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `initscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `cbreak'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `newwin'
main.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `box'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `newwin'
main.cpp:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `box'
main.cpp:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `newwin'
main.cpp:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference to `box'
main.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `refresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `keypad'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ca): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
main.cpp:(.text+0x311): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
main.cpp:(.text+0x32a): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
main.cpp:(.text+0x34d): undefined reference to `wgetch'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3af): undefined reference to `refresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to `refresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3cf): undefined reference to `keypad'
main.cpp:(.text+0x62c): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
main.cpp:(.text+0x673): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
main.cpp:(.text+0x68c): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
main.cpp:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `wgetch'
main.cpp:(.text+0x752): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
main.cpp:(.text+0x799): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7b2): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d5): undefined reference to `wgetch'
main.cpp:(.text+0x891): undefined reference to `refresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x898): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8a4): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8c0): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8cc): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8f0): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x91a): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
main.cpp:(.text+0x929): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
main.cpp:(.text+0x93f): undefined reference to `stdscr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x947): undefined reference to `wgetch'
main.cpp:(.text+0x94c): undefined reference to `endwin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [hoshiMenu] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hoshiMenu.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
The command "make" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Travis yaml -

```
language: cpp
sudo: required
dist: trusty
os: linux
compiler: gcc
addons:
    apt:
        sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test']
        packages: ['g++', 'gcc', 'cmake', 'make']
        env:
            - CXX_COMPILER=g++
            - C_COMPILER=gcc

before_install:
    - pushd ~
    - wget -O curlpp-0.8.1.tar.gz https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/archive/v0.8.1.tar.gz
    - tar -xf curlpp-0.8.1.tar.gz
    - cd curlpp-0.8.1
    - mkdir cmake_build
    - cd cmake_build
    - cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=`which ${CXX_COMPILER}` -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="$CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS" -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="$CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS" ..
    - sudo make install
    - wget -O ncurses-6.1.tar.gz https://invisible-mirror.net/archives/ncurses/ncurses-6.1.tar.gz
    - tar -xf ncurses-6.1.tar.gz
    - cd ncurses-6.1
    - ./configure
    - make
    - sudo make install
    - popd

script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - make
```

Thank you for your help <3

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Can you get Travis to show the command it's running for the "[100%] Linking CXX executable hoshiMenu" step? To see what's happened to your `-lncurses`. My best guess is that you need to put that in LDFLAGS not CXXFLAGS, but I haven't written makefiles for a while.

Comment: adding the 'LDFLAFS' instead of 'CXXFLAGS' doesn't seem to help and I don't know how to show what command it's running for the "[100%] Linking CXX executable hoshiMenu" :(

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect the code and the error message to be **in the question post**, not linked from the other sites. Please, [edit] your question post and add these required parts. For code formatting use `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. The same formatting could be used for build log.

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` will make the commands show up (that's a CMake thing). Also, you should just add `curses` to your `target_link_libraries` statement to solve your linker errors.